# ¿por que cuando quiero ejecutar la terminal en laravel me manda el siguiente error?

Tags: php

PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan on line 18

Warning: require(C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan on line 18

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan on line 18