# ¿por que cuando quiero ejecutar la terminal en laravel me manda el siguiente error?

Tags: php

> PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan on line 18

> Warning: require(C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan on line 18

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan:18
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan on line 18

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan:18
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in C:\Users\rocko\Desktop\sofia\Sofia-sitio-upt\artisan on line 18

Comment: hiciste "composer install"?

Comment: 1/ Laravel utiliza [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) para instalar dependencias y librerías, al correr `composer install` estas se descargan en la carpeta `./vendor` y se genera un archivo `./vendor/autoload.php` ( esto facilita acceder a todas las librerías o dependencias instaladas via composer con un solo require en el php ) si la instalación falla, no se completa, o no se realiza en primer lugar, puede que falte ese archivo `/vendor/autoload.php` de ahí el error de que no puede abrir el archivo.

Comment: 2/ La carpeta `./vendor` ( y todas los archivos de las dependencias y librerías ) por lo general no se incluye en los sistemas de control de versión.  Cómo sabe `composer` qué cosas instalar? hay un archivo [`composer.json`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-json-project-setup) por lo general en la raiz del proyecto que especifica que cosas y que versiones hay que descargar e instalar. Si recién descargaste el proyecto te estaría faltando el paso q indica @ffflabs

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿por que cuando quiero ejecutar la terminal en laravel me manda el siguiente error?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/604324/por-que-cuando-quiero-ejecutar-la-terminal-en-laravel-me-manda-el-siguiente-err)